# Three hyperplanes in $\Bbb P^3$ containing the same line

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Can three different hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^3$ contain the same line?

I think it can happen as we know two hyperplanes intersect in a line. So $3$ different hyperplanes can pairwise intersect in the same line. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Can someone give me an example (or otherwise a counterexample) for this statement?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: Of course. For any line in $\mathbf P^3$ there is a 1-parameter family ("pencil") of hyperplanes containing it.  Start with your favourite line, say $X=Y=0$, and see what conditions a linear form $F=aX+bY+cZ+dW$ needs to satisfy in order to vanish identically on the line.

Comment: Hint: yes; use your intuition in affine space (can you think of three planes which contain a fixed principal axis?) and then projectivize, i.e., make sure the equations cutting out your varieties are homogenous.

Comment: Linear algebra is a necessary prerequisite for algebraic geometry.

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti, thanks for the example.If I understand you correctly then in your example you are saying  $V(x,y)$ is contained in the family of hyperplanes given by $V(cz +dw)$  (and so not only $3$ hyperplanes).Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Not $V(cZ+dW)$ --- check again --- but otherwise you have the right idea.